# Mind refresher on a few simple algebra-geometry problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I feel silly for asking this, but I've completely forgotten some steps on how to do a few of these simple algebra/geometry problems.

1) Simplify $\sqrt{18x}-4\sqrt{x^3}$. I rearranged this to $3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}-4\sqrt{x^3}$. What next?

2) There is a function $a(x)$. $a(x)$ contains the point $(4,-1)$.Therefore, what point must $a^{-1}$ contain?

No clue on how to do this one.

3) Express this log equation as a single logarithm: $2\log_a x - 3\log_a y$. I yielded $\log_a \frac{x^2}{y^3}$. Is this correct?

and lastly:

4) We have the equation $X = Y_{0} * 10^z$. If $X = 80, Y_{0} = 90$, what is $z$? 
The closest I have gotten to solving this problem is: $10^z = \frac{8}{9}$.

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 1.) $4\sqrt{x^3}=4\ x \sqrt{x}$ for $x\ge 0$. What next ? 3.) Have you looked up the logarithm ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde For #1...$(\sqrt{x})(3\sqrt{2}-4x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) See the first comment

For 2) The point is (-1, 4)

For 3) OK

For 4) Just apply log to equality: $z = \log_{10}\frac{8}{9} $